# Почему дублируется ProgressBar?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Есть разметка `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/news_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_more"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Есть код `Java`:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentNews extends Fragment {

    final ArrayList<NewsClass> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    public Elements title;
    public Elements description;
    public Elements date;
    public Elements link;
    public Elements category;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    int page = 1;
    String siteUrl = "https://unspecific.ru/category/news/page/";

    private NewsAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lv;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    View v;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
        fab = v.findViewById(R.id.fab1);


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        lv = v.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Загрузка статей", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);
        new NewThread().execute();
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            try {

                Document doc;
                doc = Jsoup.connect(siteUrl + page).get();
                title = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .entry-title");
                description = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .td-excerpt");
                date = doc.select("div.td-module-meta-info > .td-post-date");
                link = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .entry-title > a");
                category = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .td-post-category");
                newsList.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < title.size() && i < date.size() && i < link.size() && i < category.size(); i++) {
                    newsList.add(new NewsClass(title.get(i).text(), date.get(i).text(), link.get(i).attr("href"), category.get(i).text()));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            ProgressBar progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            fab.show();
            lv = v.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    fab.hide();
                    lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Загрузка статей", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newsList.clear();
                    page = page + 1;
                    new NewThread().execute();
                }
            });

            if (newsList.size() == 0) {
                fab.hide();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Других статей в этой категории нет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                newsList.clear();
                page = page - 1;
                new NewThread().execute();
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                    NewsClass tempWord = (NewsClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String contentTitle = tempWord.getmTitle();
                    String contentDate = tempWord.getmDate();
                    String contentUrl = tempWord.getmUrl();
                    String contentCategory = tempWord.getmCategory();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsContent.class);
                    intent.putExtra("TITLE_KEY", contentTitle);
                    intent.putExtra("DATE_KEY", contentDate);
                    intent.putExtra("URL_KEY", contentUrl);
                    intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_KEY", contentCategory);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
}}
```

При запуске приложения появляется два кружка `ProgressBar`. Почему он появляется, понять не могу. Хотя он по идее появиться не должен. В чём проблема?

Comment: Может он у вас в активити?

Comment: Нет, только здесь.

Comment: Ну, из ниоткуда он появиться не может. Поищите по проекту откуда он может взяться. Ну и ещё можно видео снять и выложить сюда - может что-то яснее станет. Но вообще, с вероятностью 99,(9)% у вас просто в разметке 2 `ProgressBar`-a

Comment: Я не один раз все проверил на наличие дублей :) Может, из-за того, что ListView помещается в TabLayout?

Comment: У вас в разметке нет `tabLayout`... Кажется, вы не привели всю относящуюся к вопросу информацию.

Comment: Мне кажется вся проблема в том, что вы создаёте экземпляр в progressbar в каждом вызове onPostProgress(). Из-за многопоточности могут быть непредвиденные последствия.